# Convex function when λ∉[0,1].

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

f :R→R is convex, Prove, for every x,y∈R, and λ∉[0,1]

f(λx+(1−λ)y)≥λf(x)+(1−λ)f(y).

In definitoin of convex funcion λ belongs in [0,1], but here not.

Comment: Consider the picture with the line between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ and the graph of $f(x)=x^2$. That may help to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, in the definition of convexity, using $\lambda\in[0,1]$ ensures that the point $p = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$ is between $x$ and $y$:

```
x                     p           y
o---------------------o-----------o
```

With $\lambda\notin[0,1]$, this point will be *not* between $x$ and $y$.  If $\lambda < 0$, for example, it will be on the other side of $y$ from $x$:

```
x                                 y            p
o---------------------------------o------------o
```

In this situation, though, $y$ is between $x$ and $p$.  So: Find $\alpha\in[0,1]$ (in terms of $\lambda$) such that $y = \alpha x + (1-\alpha) p$, apply convexity, and see what you have.

Comment: You mean  aplly like this f(λx + (1- λ) (αx+(1−α)p ) )  ≥  λf(x)+  (1−λ)f(αx+(1−α)p ) ? I understand what happen when λ∉[0,1], but i cant understand why it proofs my equation.

Comment: No, like this: $y=\alpha x + (1-\alpha)p$, so $f(y) = f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)p) \le \dotsb$

Comment: ≤ α f(x) +(1−α)f(p) and this proofs it ?